# chunk file into pieces

Tags: c#, tcp

I have school assignment where I have to make a program that cut a different files into chunks (txt files, images...) and send it over tcp client and at the end join them back to file and save it. 
I found a solution on internet but it is not sending all the file but at the end there is a little bits missing. 
I can't find the problem. Can anybody help?

Code for cutting file:

```
      const int chunkSize = 1024; //1KB chunks
      int counter = 0;

      using (var file = File.OpenRead(filePath)) {
          int bytesRead;
          var buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
          while ((bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
               Send(ns, buffer);
          }
      }
```

Comment: It rather looks like this code would send _more_ bytes than the source file contains, because you always send the complete `buffer`, even if the last chunk read actually less than `chunksize` bytes.

Comment: [Learning how to use a debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/) is one of the most useful skills in programming.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in the code.

To illustrate, suppose you want to send a file with a chunk length of 10 and the contents:

```
 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

(For purposes of illustration, assume each character is 1 byte.)

The first call to `file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)` can fill the buffer.  The call will return the number of bytes copied to the buffer.  Because the number of characters available exceeds the buffer length, `file.Read` will write the next 10 bytes to `buffer` and return 10:

```
buffer (before call): 0000000000 (where 0 represents \0)
buffer (after call):  abcdefghij
return value of File.read: 10
```

Similarly, the second call to `file.Read` can fill the buffer with the next 10 bytes:

```
buffer (before call):  abcdefghij
buffer (after call) : klmnopqrst
return value of File.read: 10
```

For the third call, only 6 bytes remain in the file.  The call to `file.Read` will write these remaining 6 bytes to the buffer, and returns 6 to indicate that only 6 bytes are written.  The remaining 4 bytes of the buffer are not written to and retain their previous value:

```
buffer (before call) = klmnopqrst
buffer (after call)  = uvwxyzqrst
return value of File.read: 6
```

Because `Send` sends the entire buffer, the following values of `buffer` are provided as parameters to `Send`:

```
abcdefghij
klmnopqrst
uvwxyzqrst
```

Where what you probably want is:

```
abcdefghik
klmnopqrst
uvwxyz
```

So how do you fix this?

A traditional way would be to pass `bytesRead` as a parameter to your `Send` method.  Your `Send` method would need to ignore (i.e., not transmit) `buffer` contents that occur past `bytesRead`.

```
  using (var file = File.OpenRead(filePath)) {
      int bytesRead;
      var buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
      while ((bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
           Send(ns, buffer, bytesRead);
      }
```

Alternatively, you could send a smaller buffer as a parameter to `Send` in cases where the buffer is not filled:

```
  using (var file = File.OpenRead(filePath)) {
      int bytesRead;
      var buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
      while ((bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
           if (bytesRead < buffer.Length)
           {
               var smallBuffer = new byte[bytesRead];
               Array.Copy(buffer, 0, smallBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
               Send(ns, smallBuffer);
           }
           else
           {
               Send(ns, buffer);
           }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long chunkSize = 1024;
long sentBytes = 0;
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes();
byte[] fileChunk = new Byte[1024];
long fileLen = fileBytes.Length;

While (sentBytes < fileLen)
{
   if (sentBytes + chunkSize > fileLen)
       chunkSize = fileLen - sentBytes;

   Array.Copy(fileBytes, sentBytes, fileChunk, sentBytes, chunkSize);
   sentBytes += chunkSize;
   // HERE DO YOUR SENDING of fileChunk
}
```

DISCLAIMER: not tested